# Handle object array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use React for my front-end web app. When I call back-end API, I got this array:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    fullname: ABC,
    email: abc@gmail.com
    ...
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullname: DEF,
    email: def@gmail.com
    ...
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    fullname: DEF,
    email: def@gmail.com
    ...
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    fullname: GHI,
    email: ghi@gmail.com
    ...
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    fullname: ABC,
    email: abc@gmail.com
    ...
  }
]
```

Now, I need to create a new array from this old array but just contain `id` and `fullname` and not duplicates. I have try this code:

```
const oldArray = //this is the array above
const temp = [];
for (let i = 0; i < oldArray .length; i++) {
    temp.push({
    value: oldArray [i]._id,
    display: oldArray [i].fullname
  });
}
const newArray = Array.from(new Set(temp));
```

The result I receive:

```
[
  {
    value: 1,
    display: ABC
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    display: DEF
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    display: DEF
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    display: GHI
  },
  {
    value: 1,
    display: ABC
  }
]
```

As you can see, the result is still duplicated. How can I fix it?

Comment: Where in your curent logic do you think you're excluding values already in `temp`?

Comment: make temp an object, use id as the key/property, then use Object.values to convert it back to an array

Comment: In the last line, I make temp to be a Set, so i think it will avoid duplicate for temp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#filter` with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store ids that were already found.

```js
const arr=[{id:1,fullname:"ABC",email:"abc@gmail.com"},{id:2,fullname:"DEF",email:"def@gmail.com"},{id:2,fullname:"DEF",email:"def@gmail.com"},{id:3,fullname:"GHI",email:"ghi@gmail.com"},{id:1,fullname:"ABC",email:"abc@gmail.com"}];
let ids = new Set, res = arr.filter(x => !ids.has(x.id) && ids.add(x.id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tempArray=[];
const filteredArr = oldArray.filter(value =>{
 if(!tempArray.includes(value.id)) {
    tempArray.push(value.id)
    return true
   } 
 })
```

Create a tempArray, loop over the array and checks if a value exist in tempArr if not push the value into the tempArr and return true(or value)

Answer (score -1):

I know short answer but, use a `Set()` on the receiving end. Whenever you add an item to a set, use `Set.add` - it makes sure if it's a duplicate, it won't be added to the set. Sets have similar capability as arrays, but cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: While this is true and there may be a good solution here that uses a Set, it's not directly helpful because the OP is always adding different objects to the array, they just want to avoid duplicating the `value` property.